# Button or action to download webpage as .htm file?

Tags: html, outlook

Is it possible to include a button on an HTML webpage to download that page (minus the button) as a .htm file? I am setting up an Outlook Email signature generator and would like to have the output page downloadable and make it as foolproof as possible. This .htm file would then be saved to the Outlook signature directory.

Comment: You should take a look at the gazillion or so HTML or CSS generators out there.  They essentially let you visually build something, then generate the code for you to copy/paste.  Usually, the code just goes into a TEXTVIEW on the page for the user to copy out.

Comment: I need a way to save HTML that a PHP script has generated into a file. I already have the PHP script set up and is outputing HTML correctly.

Comment: Outlook doesn't follow normal HTML conventions because it uses the MS Word rendering engine, not a real browser. Get ready for your generated HTML to be badly mangled.

Comment: The code I generate looks and behaves perfectly in Outlook. However, I need photos to be linked and not embedded, and having the entire company modify .htm files manually is a bad idea.